# jquery timepicker cdnjs.cloudflare does not work

Tags: jquery, timepicker

i have a problem to run this timepicker (http://timepicker.co/) on my page.

I have this in the head

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

I have this in my script

```
var hDeb = document.createElement("input"); 
hDeb.className = "hDeb timepicker";
```

And this in a other script below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.timepicker').timepicker({});
    });
```

There is no error displayed, but the input is just an input text

Comment: You probably try to init timepicker with `$('.timepicker').timepicker({});` _before_ there's any inputs on your page. Check that your initialization happen after you add your `input`

Comment: Ok. How can i do that ?

Comment: See Rory McCrossan's answer below - _first_ he appends new element, _second_ he initializes timepicker.

Comment: Ok it works, you were right. Apologies my mistake, the div where the the timepicker is come after a click on a button so it did not work.

Comment: fen1x how can i say you fixed the problem ?

Comment: Posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try initializing timepicker before you add `<input class="timepicker">`, then your `$('.timepicker')` selector will return zero elements, and nothing'll work, as you can see in next snippet:

```js
// DOES NOT WORK
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.timepicker').timepicker();
  $('body').append('<input type="text" class="hDeb timepicker" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

You need to add input first, only then select it and initialize timepicker:

```js
// WORK
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').append('<input type="text" class="hDeb timepicker" />');
  $('.timepicker').timepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the `input` to an element in the DOM for the timepicker to be initialised on it. Try this:

```js
var hDeb = document.createElement("input");
hDeb.className = "hDeb timepicker";
document.body.appendChild(hDeb); // add this line

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.timepicker').timepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can do it purely in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('<input type="text" class="hDeb timepicker" />').appendTo('body').timepicker();
});
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say that i have `code` divHoraire.appendChild(hDeb);`code` and `code`document.body.appendChild(divHoraire);`code`

Comment: In which case what you have should work - as you can see from the snippet above. Try checking the console for errors

Comment: There is nothing in the console

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really offer any further help then, as given the information you've provided the code should be working

Answer (score 0):

try by replacing

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({});
```

by this

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker();
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css"/> your are missing closing tag salsh. it work fine from my browser

Comment: <div><input type="text" class="timepicker"></div> check input have class

Comment: Do you mean, put "/>" at the end ??

Comment: Yes when i checked the element, it has the class="timepicker"